# Text is showing through into new fragment android

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I'm new to Android and I'm making an alarm clock for practice. I have my `MainActivity` which shows a digital clock like this -

[image]

The add sign in the top right corner opens a new fragment to be able to set a new alarm but the problem is that the white digital clock text (shown in the first image) is peaking through into my fragment. I have tried to follow other suggestions that I've found on here such as setting the background to white on the fragment and also setting `statelistanimator` to `@null` but nothing has changed it. Here is the image(the overlap is on the text)-

[image]

Here is the XML for the fragment. (I have included only the parts that I believe are relevant, but i could be wrong).

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        tools:context=".SetAlarmFragment">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Choose a time"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
```

and here is the activity XML.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextClock
            android:id="@+id/textClock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/digital"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_background"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/completeAlarmSetUp"
            tools:text="12:30:01" />
```

Any help would be appreciated as well as any documentation that I can follow.

Thanks

Comment: Try to move your `<TextClock>` declaration in your `activity.xml` above `FrameLayout`. So Hierarchy will be [`ConstraintLayout`{`TextClock` , `FrameLayout`}], You dont have to change constraints, just move `FrameLayout` at the end.

Comment: @AadityaBrahmbhatt Hit the nail on the head, i feel so stupid!! please answer the question and ill mark it correct. thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move your `<TextClock>` declaration in your `activity.xml` above `FrameLayout`. So Hierarchy will be [`ConstraintLayout`{`TextClock` , `FrameLayout`}], You don't have to change constraints, just move `FrameLayout` at the end.